# Selection Sort in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, reinventing-the-wheel

I wrote a little C++ sorting routine for my Algorithm studies, but I feel that a lot can be skipped out.

I am aware that modern sort takes Iterators and comparator functions, let's disregard that for now. I just want to clean up this code. Specifically, I don't like the `if` and value variables.

I have looked into other solutions, but they didn't clear up much for me.

```
void SelectionSorter::sort(std::vector<int> &v){

    int currentIndex = 0;

    while (currentIndex < v.size()) {

        int indexOfSmallestItem = -1;
        int value = v[currentIndex];
        bool shouldSwap = false;

        for (int i = currentIndex; i < v.size(); i++) {
            if (v[i] < value) {
                value = v[i];
                indexOfSmallestItem = i;
                shouldSwap = true;
            }
        }

        if (shouldSwap) {
            int temp = v[currentIndex];
            v[currentIndex] = v[indexOfSmallestItem];
            v[indexOfSmallestItem] = temp;
        }

        currentIndex++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some points:

1. The `shouldSwap` variable is not needed. Instead, set `indexOfSmallestItem` to `currentIndex` at the beginning of the loop (this is necessary for the next step to work) and check is the `indexOfSmallestItem` is `currentIndex`:

   ```
   if (indexOfSmallestItem != currentIndex) {
       int temp = v[currentIndex];
       v[currentIndex] = v[indexOfSmallestItem];
       v[indexOfSmallestItem] = temp;
   }
   ```
2. `value` is also not needed, as you can access the vector directly:

   ```
       if (v[i] < v[indexOfSmallestItem]) {
           value = v[i];
           indexOfSmallestItem = i;
       }
   ```
3. The outside `while` loop can be a `for` loop, because:

   ```
   int currentIndex = 0; // initialization

   while (currentIndex < v.size()) { // condition

       // ...

       currentIndex++; // increment
   }
   ```

   So it would be:

   ```
   for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < v.size(); currentIndex++) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
4. You actually can start on `currentIndex + 1` because the first one is the current value.
5. The naming of the vector is not good, as one-letter names are hard to read. Change it to `vect` or something similar.

Now all you need is the `indexOfSmallestItem` and the vector:

```
void SelectionSorter::sort(std::vector<int> &vect) {

    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < vect.size(); currentIndex++) {

        int indexOfSmallestItem = currentIndex;

        for (int i = currentIndex + 1; i < vect.size(); i++) {
            if (vect[i] < vect[indexOfSmallestItem]) {
                indexOfSmallestItem = i;
            }
        }

        if (indexOfSmallestItem != currentIndex) {
            int temp = vect[currentIndex];
            vect[currentIndex] = vect[indexOfSmallestItem];
            vect[indexOfSmallestItem] = temp;
        }

    }

}
```

Optionally, you can remove the `if (indexOfSmallestItem != currentIndex)` completely, as it is not much of an improvement.

Also, you can extract the swapping part into a method. In fact, you should. This makes code (even this size) easier to maintain.

```
void SelectionSorter::sort(std::vector<int> &vect) {
    for (int currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < vect.size(); currentIndex++) {
        int indexOfSmallestItem = currentIndex;
        for (int i = currentIndex + 1; i < vect.size(); i++) {
            if (vect[i] < vect[indexOfSmallestItem]) {
                indexOfSmallestItem = i;
            }
        }
        swap(vect, currentIndex, indexOfSmallestItem);
    }
}

void swap(std::vector<int> &vect, int i, int j) {
    int temp = vect[i];
    vect[i] = vect[j];
    vect[j] = temp;
}
```

Comment: Hypothetically speaking, nothing bad happens if we swap first value with itself, is there anything to gain if we remove the if statement alltogether and keep the inside code? Can we get improvements due to not branching and not cache missing?

Comment: @Dvole Yes, nothing bad happens if swap was done on the same element, but it is more costly than the quick inequality check. It is a micro-optimization, so it can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

**Prefer high-level abstractions over low-level handcrafted code**

Functions that try to do too much often become hard to read, extend, test, and debug.  Functions should be focused and short.  An easy way to tell whether or not you should refactor your code into smaller functions is the "And"-test.  Describe what your function does.  If your descriptions uses *and*, then you should consider splitting the function into its parts.  For your selection sort, you would describe it by:

> Iterate over each element. Find the index of the minimum element from the remaining elements *and* swap if that index is not our current index.

Write the small and focused `min_element_index()` and `swap()` functions.

```
#include <vector>

std::size_t min_element_index(const std::vector<int>& vec,
                              std::size_t startingIndex = 0) {
    for (auto candidate = startingIndex + 1; candidate < vec.size();
         ++candidate) {
        if (vec[candidate] < vec[startingIndex]) {
            startingIndex = candidate;
        }
    }
    return startingIndex;
}

void swap_by_index(std::vector<int>& vec, int first, int second) {
    const auto temp = vec[first];
    vec[first] = vec[second];
    vec[second] = temp;
}
```

Let `sort()` be a composed function of those two small, focused, and tested functions.

```
void SelectionSorter::sort(std::vector<int>& vec) {
    for (auto currentIndex = 0; currentIndex < vec.size(); ++currentIndex) {
        const auto indexOfSmallestItem = min_element_index(vec, currentIndex);
        swap_by_index(vec, currentIndex, indexOfSmallestItem);
    }
}
```

We gain reusable functions, avoid magic numbers (`-1`), and can `const`-qualify our immutable objects.

**Prefer to treat warnings as errors**

For these small learning programs and new code bases, turn up your warning level and treat warnings as errors.  Older code bases should continue to use the same rules that are already being used.

You have mismatched sign comparisons for each `std::vector<int>::size()` comparison.

**Use the C++ Style Declarator Layout**

```
void SelectionSorter::sort(std::vector<int>& v) {
-------------------------------------------^
```

Also wasn't sure if the missing space before the `{` was intended.  Utilize extensions/tools (Clang-Format, Astyle, etc) to maintain the style layout.